# How can I get the txt information by line and split each line for separate classes

Tags: loops, readlines

I have a text file with three lines of code and need to take each line and split it by "," so I can take the pieces from each line and place them into a class. I'll have one class for each line.

This is what I have come up with sofar. I just think it's too much code and would like to find a simple way to do this.

The text file looks like this

```
character, stats, stats, stats
weapon, stats
armor, stats
```

my code for the first line looks like this

````
class CharacterFight(
       var name : String,
       var race : String,
       var hitpoints :Int,
       var strength : Int,
       var agility : Int,

){
override fun toString(): String {
       return """Character
           Name: ${name}
           Race: ${race}
           Hitpoints :${hitpoints}
           Strength: ${strength}
           Agility: ${agility}
       """.trimMargin()
   }
}
var charactersStats = mutableListOf<CharacterFight>()
var charStats = mutableListOf<String>()
   val fileName: String = "src/main/kotlin/gimli.txt"
   var  characterInfo = mutableListOf<String>()
var lines = File(fileName).readLines()
   for (line in lines){
       val pieces  = line.split("\n")
       characterInfo.add(line)
   }
    charStats.add(characterInfo[0])
   for (stat in charStats){
       var statpieces = stat.split(",")
      var charpieces = CharacterFight(statpieces[0],statpieces[1],statpieces[2].toInt(),statpieces[3].toInt(),statpieces[4].toInt)
       charactersStats.add(charpieces)
   }```
````

Comment: what you have there looks like an unstructured CSV. I would remove the `\n` from the file, then just read it as a normal csv with a single row (you might need to trim your ints because you have spaces, or replace `,space` with `,`).

Comment: That would be nice but I have to read the file as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid boilerplate `toString()` code consider using [data classes](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html):

```kotlin
data class CharacterFight(var name: String, var race: String, var hitpoints: Int, var strength: Int, var agility: Int)
```

Assuming that other two classes are

```kotlin
data class Weapon(val name: String, val value: Int)
data class Armor(val name: String, val value: Int)
```

CSV deserializing could be done in the following manner (usage of [destructuring declarations](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/multi-declarations.html) makes code more readable, but explicit `toInt()` convertion on a certain passing arguments still can't be avoided):

```
fun deserializeCSV(fileName: String): Triple<CharacterFight, Weapon, Armor> {
    val (characterInfo, weaponInfo, armorInfo) = File(fileName).readLines().map { it.split(",") }
    val character = run { //create separate scope to avoid clash of name variables
        val (name, race, hitpointsStr, strengthStr, agilityStr) = characterInfo
        CharacterFight(name, race, hitpointsStr.toInt(), strengthStr.toInt(), agilityStr.toInt())
    }
    val weapon = run { //create separate scope to avoid clash of name variables
        val (name, valueStr) = weaponInfo
        Weapon(name, valueStr.toInt())
    }
    val armor = run { //create separate scope to avoid clash of name variables
        val (name, valueStr) = armorInfo
        Armor(name, valueStr.toInt())
    }
    return Triple(character, weapon, armor)
}
```

If provided CSV format is not a hard requirment, I would recomend to use JSON instead:

```
{"name":"Gimli","race":"dwarf","hitpoints":90,"strength":40,"agility":3}
{"name":"Axe","value":25}
{"name":"Plate male","value":85}
```

Then with help of [kotlinx.serialization](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization) library deserialization is fairly easy:

```kotlin
//don't forget to add `@Serializable` annotation to all deserializable classes

fun deserializeJSON(fileName: String): Triple<CharacterFight, Weapon, Armor> {
    val (characterInfo, weaponInfo, armorInfo) = File(fileName).readLines()
    val character: CharacterFight = Json.decodeFromString(characterInfo)
    val weapon: Weapon = Json.decodeFromString(weaponInfo)
    val armor: Armor = Json.decodeFromString(armorInfo)
    return Triple(character, weapon, armor)
}
```

Comment: How would I go about this if I want the name of the weapon and armor in a separate class?

Comment: You mean something like `data class WeaponName(val name: String)` and `data class Weapon(val name: WeaponName, val value: Int)`?

Then you need to mark `WeaponName` as `@Serializable` too, and adjust JSON accordingly: `{"name": {"name": "Axe"},"value":25}`.

Comment: Define any data structure you want, then try to `print(Json.encodeToString())` it with some dummy data and see how JSON should look like so that it could be deserialized back.